# PyOpenGL: Why does "glutCreateWindow" suddenly make my application crash?

Tags: python-3.x, glut, pyopengl, glutcreatewindow

Can someone please explain to me why the following code does not work anymore? And maybe help me get it to work again?

(Python 3.5.2 32bit)

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
glutInit()
glutInitWindowSize(600, 400)
glutCreateWindow(b'window')
```

I was using it like this on windows for a long time without any problems. But now it crashes:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WKXy.png)

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing looks immediately wrong with that code and it is surprising that the window stays open and becomes unresponsive! For me on windows 10 64bit, your code runs and immediately closes the window. Have you tried calling `glutMainLoop` and defining a `glutDisplayFunc`?

Comment: @user2588654 thanks for your hint. I tried the code on a python 64bit interpreter. There it works fine. But on 32bit it crashes. Something must have changed within windows that messed up the 32bit version of pyopengl. It worked before as for the 64bit case on windows 10 64bit.